# Does kafka consumer manages its state?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a Kafka cluster set up using three GCP VM instances. All three VMs have Zookeepers and servers running on then.

I followed this guide for my set up: [How to Setup Multi-Node Multi Broker Kafka Cluster in AWS](https://codeforgeek.com/how-to-setup-multi-node-multi-broker-kafka-cluster-in-aws/)

I have kept all three instances in different regions in order to achieve High Availability in case of regional failure in Cloud Service (GCP or AWS, I understand it is highly unlikely).

I have a topic created with replication-factor as `3`. Now, suppose one region goes entirely down and only two nodes are alive. What happens to a consumer who was reading from the VM in the failed (which was working previously)?

Once the services in the region come back up, would this consumer (having a unique client_id) maintain its state and read only new messages?

Also, what if I have 7 VMs divided (2,2,3) across 3 regions:

1. Is it a good idea to keep the replication factor as `7` to achieve high availability?
2. I am thinking of 7 VMs because any of the regions go down, we still have the majority of Kafka nodes running. Is it possible to run a Kafka cluster with majority of nodes down? (E.g 4 out of 7 nodes down)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Kafka provides various setting to achieve high availability and can be tuned and optimize based on the requirement

**1. min.insync.replicas:** Is the minimum number of copies will be always live at any time to continue running the Kafka cluster. e.g. lets we have 3 broker nodes and one broker node got down in that case if min.insync.replicas = 2 or less cluster will keep serving request however if min.insync.replicas 3 it will stop. Please note min.insync.replicas=1 is not advisable in that case if data lost will be lost forever.
min.insync.replicas is a balance between higher consistency (requiring writes to more than one broker) and higher availability (allowing writes when fewer brokers are available).

**2. ack(Acknowledgements):**
While publishing the message we can set how many replicas commit before the producer receives acknowledge.
e.g. ack is 0 means immediately acknowledge the message without waiting for any commit to partition.
ack is 1 means get success acknowledge after the message gets to commit to the leader.
ack is all means acknowledge after all in-sync replicas committed.

**leader.election.enable:** You can set unclean.leader.election.enable=true on your brokers and in this case, if no replicas are in-sync, one of the out-of-sync replicas will be elected. This can lead to data loss but is favoring availability. Of course, if some replicas are in-sync it will still elect one of them

**offsets.topic.replication.factor**: should be greater than in case __consumer_offsets to have high available.  __consumer_offsets is an offset topic to manage topic offset so in case you have a topic replication factor is 1 it may fail to the consumer if one broker got down

**__consumer_offsets** maintain committed for each topic of the consumer group.

The consumer always reads from a leader partition Consumers do not consume from followers, the followers only exist for redundancy and fail-over. There are possibilities that a failed broker consists of multiple leader partition.  So in that case followers from a partition on other brokers will get promoted to leaders.
Their different scenario lets follower partition doesn't have 100% in-sync with leader partition then we might lose some data. Here scenario comes how or what ack you're using while publishing messages.

There is a trade-off on how many partitions or replication is the best number. I can say it depend on design and choice based on the discussion. Please make note a large number of the replica will give overburden which doing  ISR with all follower partition with more memory occupied whereas very less like 1 or 2 will better performance but not high availability.

**Broker controller**
The controller is one of the brokers that have additional partition and replica management responsibilities. It has some extra responsibility and stores some meta details and response in any meta details change in the partition.

Any of the brokers can play the role of the controller, but in a healthy cluster, there is exactly one controller. Kafka broker will get reflected another controller in case the controller shutdown or the zookeeper lost connection.
If the controller is 0 or more than 1 means the Broker is not healthy

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Is it possible to keep the Kafka cluster running in case maximum number of nodes goes down? (For e.g: 7 total nodes are there and 4 go down)

Comment: Updated about Broker controller....in general if N in-sync replica it can handle N-1 failover.